# Programming Languages where a keyword is needed to specify that the method is extended from its parent class

Tags: python, oop, programming-languages

Forgive me for my ignorance, but does anyone know any languages that strictly enforce the condition I've given on the title? For example, using Python syntax, we can extend a class with a new method like this

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

But is there a language that needs an additional keyword, let's say `new`, to specify that this method is unique to the child class and is not an override of the methods of its parent class/es? For example:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def new foo(self):
        pass
```

I am asking this because, when I am working on a project that requires multiple inheritance such as `class B(A, C, D)`, and I saw a method defined in `B`, I need to check if the given method is from one of its parent class or its own method, and I find it extremely tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think of is the `@Override` annotation in Java, which can be applied to a method declaration in order for the compiler to check that it overrides an inherited method (or implements an interface method).

When used in conjunction with a linter which checks that all method overrides are annotated with `@Override`, then your IDE will give you a linter warning when you omit the annotation. [IntellIJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html#inheritance-issues) and [SonarSource](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1161) both have linter rules for this, for example.

So long as you are strict about obeying the linter warning, then it's "strict" in that sense, but of course linter warnings don't actually prevent your code from being compiled or executed. Nonetheless, I don't know of a closer example from a real programming language. Unfortunately Java doesn't have multiple inheritance so it's not directly applicable to your problem.